# set the original list on the adapter when SearchView's query is empty

Tags: android

I have a SearchView and a RecyclerView inside my Fragment and i created a getFilter method for adding search functionality but my problem is this SearchView is not working as it should I'm facing a problem which is explained below

once i enter something on the `SearchView` i get the Result but when when i start deleting the last words of my query one by one i didn't get anything as result and after performing a query when i delete the whole text which is inside my SearchView i am not getting back my original List instead am getting blank RecyclerView

[here you can see i performed the search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e02vl.png)

[this is what happens when i delete the keywords (no results)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thzwd.png)

this is how i created the `GetFilter` inside my adapter class

```
 private static class UserFilter extends Filter {

    private final NotesAdapter adapter;

    private final List<Information> originalList;

    private final List<Information> filteredList;

    private UserFilter(NotesAdapter adapter, List<Information> originalList) {
        super();
        this.adapter = adapter;
        this.originalList = new LinkedList<>(originalList);
        this.filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        filteredList.clear();
        final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            filteredList.addAll(originalList);

        } else {
            final String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for (final Information user : originalList) {
                if (user.title.contains(filterPattern)) {
                    filteredList.add(user);
                }
            }
        }
        results.values = filteredList;
        results.count = filteredList.size();
        return results;
    }


    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        adapter.filteredUserList.clear();
        adapter.filteredUserList.addAll((ArrayList<Information>) results.values);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    } }
```

and this is how am using this method in my fragment

```
   Search_View.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

                                       @Override
                                       public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String Text) {

                                           Log.v(""+Text , " searchView TextSubmit" );
                                           Log.d("tag", "notesAdapter=" + notesAdapter);
                                           notesAdapter.getFilter().filter(Text);


                                           return true;
                                       }



                                       @Override
                                       public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                                           Log.v(""+newText , " searchView TextChange" );
                                           Log.d("tag", "notesAdapter=" + notesAdapter);
                                           notesAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                                           return true;

                                       }
                                   });
```

if anybody knows what am doing wrong than please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code:

Fragment:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

        final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {    
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {

                final List<Friend> filteredModelList = filter(myFriendsList, query);
                myFriendsListAdapter.animateTo(filteredModelList);
                myFriendsRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);

                return true;
            }
        });
    }


    private List<Friend> filter(List<Friend> models, String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();

        final List<Friend> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Friend model : models) {
            final String currentAddress = model.getFriendName().toLowerCase();
            if (currentAddress.contains(query)) {
                filteredModelList.add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        myFriendsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        myFriendsList = new ArrayList<>();

        initDatasetList();

        myFriendsListAdapter = new MyFriendsListAdapter(getActivity(), myFriendsList);
        myFriendsRecyclerView.setAdapter(myFriendsListAdapter);
    }
```

Adapter:

```
private LayoutInflater mInflater = null;
  private List<Friend> contactList;

    public MyFriendsListAdapter(List<Friend> contactList) {
        this.contactList = contactList;
    }

public MyFriendsListAdapter(Context context, List<Friend> models) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    contactList = new ArrayList<>(models);
}

public Friend removeItem(int position) {
    final Friend model = contactList.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    return model;
}

public void addItem(int position, Friend model) {
    contactList.add(position, model);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void moveItem(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    final Friend model = contactList.remove(fromPosition);
    contactList.add(toPosition, model);
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
}

public void animateTo(List<Friend> models) {
    applyAndAnimateRemovals(models);
    applyAndAnimateAdditions(models);
    applyAndAnimateMovedItems(models);
}


private void applyAndAnimateRemovals(List<Friend> newModels) {
    for (int i = contactList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        final Friend model = contactList.get(i);
        if (!newModels.contains(model)) {
            removeItem(i);
        }
    }
}

private void applyAndAnimateAdditions(List<Friend> newModels) {
    for (int i = 0, count = newModels.size(); i < count; i++) {
        final Friend model = newModels.get(i);
        if (!contactList.contains(model)) {
            addItem(i, model);
        }
    }
}

private void applyAndAnimateMovedItems(List<Friend> newModels) {
    for (int toPosition = newModels.size() - 1; toPosition >= 0; toPosition--) {
        final Friend model = newModels.get(toPosition);
        final int fromPosition = contactList.indexOf(model);
        if (fromPosition >= 0 && fromPosition != toPosition) {
            moveItem(fromPosition, toPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

Friend class (yours is Information):

```
public String friendName;

public String getFriendName() {
        return friendName;
    }
```

and the menu in the xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:menuCategory="secondary"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="@string/search"/>
```

Hopes it helps.

Comment: hey @Mor thanks for helping :) i replay appreciate this , but mine method of implementation is kinda deferent than yours and mine is also working except one thing and that is when my searchView is empty am not getting my original list displayed in my RecyclerView